# can't load font webpack and angular2

Tags: angular, webpack

I have problem with include font in my app angular2-webpack, I have download this starter:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter,
But now when I try to add :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SuperMarioBros';
    src: url('./SuperMarioBros.eot');
    src: local('SuperMarioBros'), url('./SuperMarioBros.woff') format('woff'), url('./SuperMarioBros.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

webpack compiler return these error:

```
./src/assets/fonts/super_mario/SuperMarioBros.eot
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\lorenzo\src\assets\fonts\super_mario\SuperMarioBros.eot Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

./src/assets/fonts/super_mario/SuperMarioBros.woff
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\lorenzo\src\assets\fonts\super_mario\SuperMarioBros.woff Unexpected character ' '

./src/assets/fonts/super_mario/SuperMarioBros.ttf
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Lorenzo\Desktop\lorenzo\src\assets\fonts\super_mario\SuperMarioBros.ttf Unexpected character ' '
```

And in my **webpack.config.js** I have this loader:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      // Pass *.jsx files through jsx-loader transform
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['react-hot','jsx?harmony'] },

      {test: /\.(png|jp?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'},
      {test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/, loader : 'file-loader'}


    ]
  }
```